# Use to_char in Flask SqlAlchemy query

Tags: postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

In my Flask model I have this column:

```
datetime = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now)
```

When I populate the rows from a PostgreSql database I get this:

```
2020-07-03 18:12:49.362271
2020-07-04 09:21:34.644202
```

Now, I want to format those results using the `to_char` function from Postgresql. The query shoudl be this:

```
select to_char(datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as datetime from order_detail;
```

And the result is this:

```
---------------------
 2020-07-03 18:12:49
 2020-07-04 09:21:34
(2 rows)
```

How can I tell Flask-SqlAlchemy to execute that function when it queries the `order_detail` table?.

**Important: I don't want to do the formatting in my Flask app, I want to let Postgresql format the results**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`column_property()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property) and `func()`. Assuming your model is named `Foo`:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property

class Foo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    datetime = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now)
    formatted_datetime = column_property(func.to_char(datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))

# print(Foo.query.all()[0].formatted_datetime)
# ->'2020-07-04 06:59:09'
```

If it's important that the model's attribute name be `datetime`, you'll need to give the underlying column a different attribute name and reference the column using it's `name` kwarg.

```
class Foo2(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    orig_datetime = db.Column(db.DateTime, name='datetime', nullable=False, default=datetime.now)
    datetime = column_property(func.to_char(orig_datetime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))

# print(Foo2.query.all()[0].datetime)
# ->'2020-07-04 06:59:09'
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.